# How to call a function in the children first then call a function in parent

Tags: reactjs

```js
<span onClick={this.handleSecond}>
  <button onClick={this.handleFirst} />
</span>
```

how to call function handleFrist then call fuction handleSecond

Comment: you should call `handleDownload` function from `handleFirst`function

Comment: thank you. do you have any other way?

Comment: I think it will be beneficial to rethink the problem you are trying to solve.  There is most likely a better way to accomplish what you desire.

Comment: Actually, it works that way. When you click button it fires button click then it will fire span click handler it called event propagation you can check it by logging a values in both functions.

Answer (score 0):

pass the function that has the promise aswell as props/state from your HOC into your child component

Higher order component

```
const HOC = () => {

  [state, setState] = useState()

  const onClickHandler = () =>  firstChange().then(() => {
    setState();
    secondChange
  })

  return(
    <ChildComponent onClickHandler={onClickHandler} state={state} />
  )
}
```

Child Component

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

  const [onClickHandler, state] = props


  return(
    <p>{state}</p>
    <button onClick={() => onClickHandler()}>A Button</button>
  )
}
```

you can make handleFirst a promise if it isnt already and then .then(handleSecond)

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
}, 300);
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
console.log(value);
// expected output: "foo"
});

console.log(promise1);
// expected output: [object Promise]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise